# How does this sed command work?

Tags: sed

I've come across this solution for printing a specific line from a text file:

```
sed '123!d;q' file
```

Why doesn't sed quit after the first line of input in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In English, this `sed` program means: for each line,

- [`123!`] if the current line number is not 123, then [`d`] delete the current line and start the next cycle (i.e. move to the next line);
- then (but we only reach this point if the `d` command was not executed), [`q`] exit without processing any more lines (but do print out the current line in our dying throes).

Or if you prefer, in shell syntax:

```
line_number=0
while IFS= read -r pattern_space; do
  line_number=$(($line_number+1))
  if [ $line_number -ne 123 ]; then       # 123!
    continue                              #   d
  fi
  echo "$pattern_space"; break            # q
  echo "$pattern_space"                   # implicit final print (never reached)
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it to me also. My error was that I understood `!` was connected to `d`, not `123`.

Comment: @Gilles: missing the braces `{d;q;}`, shouldn't `q` apply to every line (so only the first)?

Comment: @enzotib `q` applies to every line where it's executed. But when the line number is not 123, the `d` command is executed, and its meaning is to skip immediately to the next input line.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation

Comment: Essentially it does the same as `sed -n 123p` (prints the same output) except it *stops* after line 123 rather than processing potentially thousands more lines that it will never do anything with anyways.